# Need help in login TS file in order to redirect to specific pages

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-ui-router

I have created backend API in node aand want to integrate it on the front end now.
below is my login API which is working fine.

```
login: (req, res ) =>{
    const body = req.body;
    getUserByUserEmail(body.email, (err, results) => {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        if(!results) {
            return res.json({
                success : 0 ,
                message : "Invalid Email or Password"
            });
        }

        const result = compareSync( body.password, results[0].password);
        if (result) {
            results[0].password = "";
            const jsontoken = sign({ result: results }, "qwe123", {expiresIn : "3h"});
            // console.log(results[0])
            // Admin part
            if(results[0].role=='admin')
            {
                        return res.json({
                            success : 1 ,
                            message : "You are Successfully logged in as admin!",
                            token : jsontoken,
                            
                        });
            }
            // Employee part
            else {
               
            return res.json({
                            success : 1 ,
                            message : "You are Successfully logged in as user!",
                            token : jsontoken,
                            
                        });
            }

         }
        else{
            return res.json({
                success : 0 ,
                message : "Invalid Email or Password"
            });
        }
  
    });
}
```

this is my TS file for login i want to redirect admin to specific page and employee to specific page but not redirecting after login.currently the below code is showing alert of success message as i login as admin or employee but not redirecting to the routes

```
  onSubmit() {


    if(this.form.valid){

      this.userdataService.login(this.form.value).subscribe(result=>{

      if(result.role=='admin'){
        //generate token and shown in console
     // console.log(result);
      localStorage.setItem('token is',result.token);
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/employee-list');

      }
      else if(result.role=='employee'){
        localStorage.setItem('token is',result.token);
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/log-Page');
      }
      else{
      alert(result.message);
      }
      });
      }

  }
```

Comment: have u try checking the api response? is 'console.log(result);' give you the right result from your api? or try putting the log before if condition n check the result?

Comment: yes for admin credentials it returns admin as role and for employee credentials it return employee.
 
onSubmit() {


    if(this.form.valid){

      this.userdataService.login(this.form.value).subscribe(result=>{

      if(result.success){

      console.log(result);



      }
      else{


      }
      });
      }

  }